# Can i merge 2 continuous empty string in a list into 1 empty string, so that when we have 4 empty string then it should merge and make 2 empty string

Tags: python, regex, list, replace, merge

I want to merge 2 continuous empty string in a list and make it into 1 empty string. For example if it finds 4 continuous empty string then it should make 2 empty string out of it. In Python.

```
str_list = ['hi',' ',' ','hello',' ',' ',' ',' ','bye']

Desired Output : ['hi',' ','hello',' ',' ','bye']
```

Comment: What must be the result for `str_list = ['hi',' ','hello',' ',' ',' ','bye']` (odd number of spaces)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it works:

```
count=0
l2=[]
for i in str_list:
    if i==' ':
        count+=1
        if (count%2)==0:
            l2.append(' ')
            count=0
    else:
        l2.append(i)
```

Comment: Be aware that will remove all single space like in  `str_list = ['hi',' ','hello']` that will  become `str_list = ['hi','hello']`

Answer (score 1):

you can  use a `while` loop:

```
i = 0
new_list = []
while i < len(str_list) - 1:
    if str_list[i] == str_list[i + 1] == ' ':
        new_list.append(' ')
        i += 2
    else:
        new_list.append(str_list[i])
        i += 1

# grab the last character if last 2 are not ' '
if i < len(str_list):
     new_list.append(str_list[i])

print(new_list)
```

**output:**

```
['hi', ' ', 'hello', ' ', ' ', 'bye']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
count = 0
new_list = []
for i in str_list:
    if i == ' ' and count == 0:
        count = count + 1
    elif i == ' ' and count % 2 == 0:
        for j in range(count // 2):
            new_list.append(' ')
    else:
        new_list.append(i)
        count = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to remove all single space:

```
words = ["hi", " ", " ", "hello", " ", " ", " ", " ", "bye", " "]

rv = []

d = " "
skip = True

for i in words:
    if i == d:
        skip = not skip
        if skip:
            continue
    rv.append(i)

print(rv)
```

Output:

```
['hi', ' ', 'hello', ' ', ' ', 'bye', ' ']
```